# access to the fields of a class TypeScript with React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm working with React, TypeScript and axios for HTTP requests.
When I do axios.get (myURL) I get my data in this format:

```
[["value1","value2"],["value3","value4"],["value5","value6"]]
```

I created a class that represents a string array. Here is the code:

```
import  Serializable  from '../interface/serializable';

export default class Row {
    public row:string[];
}
```

And here is the code of the component in which I would like to use this class :

```
import Row from '../class/row';

interface IColumnSelectionState {
    readonly data: Row[],
}
    class MyDataextends React.Component<any,IColumnSelectionState>{

            constructor(props: any) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    data: [],
                }
                this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
            }

   private submit():void{
                axios.get("myURL").then(res => {
                    const response = res.data;
                    this.setState({ data: response });
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
            }
        }
```

The problem when I execute the "submit()" method and I'm doing :

```
 console.log (this.state.data) // I see my data in the format described    above
```

but when I do :

```
console.log (this.state.data [0].row) // this shows me undefined while I declared my array in the Row class
```

I really need to get the first array to loop it and do the treatments.

If anyone has an idea of how to do this thank you for helping me !

thank you in advance !!!

Comment: Do you need to initialize 'this.state.data' in the constructor? If so, you should assign it a new Row[], not [].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `row` in the format presented. There's also an unnecessary space in the log. 
Try `console.log(this.state.data[0];`

Answer (score 0):

it returns me an instance of Row. So normally if I do `"this.state.data [0] .row"` it should send me a string array because Row has a property `"row: string []"`

Comment: Look at your format. Do you see `row` anywhere? Either reformat the data you are fetching or access it as I instructed in my answer. And again, mind your spaces!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Barazu. Let me take a different approach to the problem. The data field you’re getting back is itself of type ‘Row’. I’ve tweaked the Axios request ever so slightly to demonstrate. (Apologies for the formatting in advance)

```
           axios.get("myURL").then(res: AxiosResponse<Row> => { // added a type here to res
                const response = res.data; // response is a Row[]
                this.setState({ data: response });
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
```

Here, Axios uses generics to state the payload (the data field)is of type Row is not a field or property on ‘data’ but ‘data’ is of type ‘Row[]’.

I’m not sure where you need to iterate on this data, but I’m gonna take a guess it’s once it’s on the state of the component. Then you should be able to do something like this once the data is retrieved

```
const myRows: Row[] = this.state.data;
for (const row of myRows) { console.log(myRow[0]); }
```